# Unknown type in Immutable object

Tags: typescript, immutable.js

I am using Typescript 5.3.3 and I have reducer code that generates ts(2345) errors.

The reducer looks like this:

```
const initialState = Immutable.fromJS({
  isLoading: false,
})

const myReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOAD':
      return state.set('isLoading', false)   <--- ERROR
    default: return state
  }
}
```

This version generates an error on the marked line:

```
Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Map<"valueOf", Map<never, never>> | Map<"valueOf", Map<never, never>>'.ts(2345)
```

I have tried introducing an interface like this:

```
interface State {
  isLoading: boolean
}

const initialState : State = Immutable.fromJS({   <--- ERROR 1
  isLoading: false,
})

const myReducer = (state: State = initialState, action) : State => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOAD':
      return state.set('isLoading', false)   <--- ERROR 2
    default: return state
  }
}
```

But that generates two errors as marked above:

1. `Property 'isLoading' is missing in type 'Map<"isLoading", Map<"valueOf", Map<never, never>>>' but required in type 'State'.ts(2741)`
2. `Property 'set' does not exist on type 'State'.ts(2339)`

The weird thing is that I have pretty much identical reducers (of the first type, i.e. with no interfaces) in other files where this works fine, so not sure why it doesn't work here.

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of Immutable are you using? You probably should be using v4 as it will probably have the right typings. https://immutable-js.com/#using-typescript-with-immutablejs-v4

Comment: With that said, you probably shouldn't bother using Immutable with the state and continue to recreate the next state by hand. The state should be immutable by convention, not by implementation.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using v4.

Comment: This is a very simple version of my reducer. The actual one has lots of nested objects that get updated, using `set`, `setIn`, and `merge` functions on the immutable. Would be quite the undertaking to rewrite.

Comment: The style of Redux you are writing is outdated. You should *really* consider updating/integrating [Redux-Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) and cut out much of your Redux boilerplate and get immutability for "free", e.g. you write reducers that use mutable updates to a draft state.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring `initialState` to be of type `State`. However, the value you are assigning to `initialState` is the return value of `Immutable.fromJS()`. This is the cause of your first error.

Your second error is caused since TypeScript expects `state` to be of type `State`. Since your `State` type only consists of the single property `isLoading`, `state.set()` is not found.

That being said, your initial code, works without error with TypeScript using immutable@4.3.4 on Node 21.1 with TypeScript 5.2.2.

Comment: I should have mentioned that the code does compile and run correctly. But the Typescript check on commit fails the code.

Comment: @Clutchplate On a pipeline? I'm using `tsc test.ts` with types for `immutable` and `node` installed and it's not complaining?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it would depend on how you import immutable. The problem appears to be that the `initialState` is not typed correctly. The call to `fromJS()` should be to the generic overload [`fromJS<JSValue>()`](https://github.com/immutable-js/immutable-js/blob/main/type-definitions/immutable.d.ts#L5198C9-L5198C9) which should return a correctly typed result. I don't know if you can do this with the state `Immutable.fromJS()` call. Try importing that instead.

i.e.,

```
import { fromJS } from 'immutable';
...
const initialState = fromJS({
  isLoading: false,
}); // may need to add `as const` to the arg to force the type
```